# mutt: automatically fetch remote IMAP folder list

Tags: imap, mutt

I know that I can explicitly set a remote IMAP folder in .muttrc

```
mailboxes imaps://$my_server/INBOX.myfolder
```

I have some 30 folders in my account: is it possible to have mutt to automatically fetch the IMAP remote folders list so that I can navigate them?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option for your config file:

```
imap_check_subscribed
       Type: boolean
       Default: no

       When set, mutt will fetch the set of subscribed folders from
       your server on connection, and add them to the set of mailboxes
       it polls for new mail just as if you had issued individual
       “mailboxes” commands.
```

Of course this only works for subscribed folders and only after your first connection to the server.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t specify what you actually see and how you try to “fetch the IMAP remote folders list” but the default behaviour when Mutt is compiled with IMAP support is to list *all* folders. Presumably, your Mutt configuration contains changes from the default settings.

---

By default, when Mutt browses the list of available IMAP folders (e.g., after using `c` to open another mailbox), it uses the IMAP [LIST Command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.3.8) to retrieve the list of folders and the server returns **all** folders that exist for the user’s account.

To change this behaviour, the [`imap_list_subscribed`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#imap-list-subscribed) configuration option can be set to *yes*. In this case, Mutt uses the IMAP [LSUB Command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.3.9) when retrieving folder names from the server: this retrieves *only* the list of folders that are marked as being *subscribed* on the IMAP server.

> This variable configures whether IMAP folder browsing will look for only
> subscribed folders or all folders.